# Create Component does not work! MetaUml: Using MetaPost in LuaLaTeX

Tags: metapost, metauml

I am trying to create a component diagram using [MetaUml](https://github.com/ogheorghies/MetaUML) embedded in TeX using LuaLaTeX. Every example form [the manual](https://github.com/ogheorghies/MetaUML/releases/download/v0.2.5/metauml_manual_0.2.5.pdf) I tried, worked well except from components.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\title{Algo}
\author{Paul}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Reengineering Algo Architecture}
\subsection{Current System Structure}
\subsection{Restructured System}
\subsection{Extended  Restructured System}
    \subsubsection{System Component Structure}
        \begin{mplibcode}
            input metauml;
            beginfig(1);
            Component.C("Business Logic")();
            drawObject(C);
            endfig;
            end
        \end{mplibcode}
    \subsubsection{Inner Component Structure}
    \subsubsection{Usecasses}
\end{document}
```

This does not work for me, but it should, [see page 14](https://github.com/ogheorghies/MetaUML/releases/download/v0.2.5/metauml_manual_0.2.5.pdf).

Error Message is:

[image: Error Message]

[image: Error Message]]

Cannot figure it out. Sorry.

Edit: Automatic installation was not correct:[image: Fixed installation]

But it is still not working.

Comment: please fix your example so that people can run it and debug the issue, make it a complete small document not a fragment with `[...]`

Comment: Your example runs fine for me on TeX Live 2017.  (Once I add the missing begin/end document environment).  Are you sure you have metauml installed?

Comment: If I comment out the `input metauml;` line, I get the same errors as you are seeing in your log.  So my guess is that you don't have metauml installed properly.

Comment: @Thruston yeah that could be a thing. I am new to TeX at all. I use texmaker. Do you got a link for me, on how to install it? Much appreciated.

Comment: http://metauml.sourceforge.net/old/installation-howtos.html

Comment: But I'm not sure that is current.

Comment: Look in your MikTeX packager manager (or whatever it provides nowadays) .

Comment: A a sidenote, the `end` instruction of MetaPost is not necessary in a `mplibcode` environment.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows

Comment: @Thruston I think it is installed. I found it in D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\metapost\generic\metauml

Comment: @Franck Pastor Thx

Comment: Is TexMaker actually using MikTeX?

Comment: According to the log you posted it is...

Comment: They are two independent devices which can work with each other. MikTeX is a TeX distribution (which I never use myself since I'm not on Windows), and Texmaker can be seen as an interface to it. More precisely, Texmaker is an external text editor with a PDF viewer included besides. It handles the code you write, transmits it to a TeX Distribution (in your case MikTeX), which digests it and produces the output file which Texmaker shows afterwards.

Comment: I fixed the installation and now I get a diffrent warning: (luamplib)               ! I can't open file `metauml_component'.
(luamplib)               l.77 input metauml_component

Comment: metauml_component is existing. I deleted all .mp and inserted the data from the official [GitHub-Repo](https://github.com/ogheorghies/MetaUML). Still not working, cant explain this. See also edit.

Comment: You may want to set `MPINPUTS` to include `"D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\metapost\generic\metauml"` or have a look at `texmf.cnf`. See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484017/mpinputs-of-metapost, https://mailman.speleo.sk/pipermail/therion/2015-June/005478.html