# MPINPUTS of metapost

Tags: paths, metapost, texlive-2018

When I ran `mpost` in a source directory, it worked fine. When I set MPINPUTS with `$export MPINPUTS=./src`, I saw an error

`I can't find the 'plain' preload file!`

I wonder if my export command somehow cleared a default path of the 'plain' preload file.

mactex 2018.0417
MetaPost, version 2.00 (TeX Live 2018) (kpathsea version 6.3.0)

Comment: like all tex paths you want  `MPINPUTS=./src:` where the trailing `:` means add to the the default path

Comment: Thanks, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like all tex paths you want

```
MPINPUTS=./src:
```

where the trailing `:` means add to the the default path